# Вопрос по таблицам Googledocs

Tags: google-docs

Есть скрипт, который достает данные с сайта в виде *XML* и записывает их в таблицу *googledocs*.

Скрипт достает 2 параметра: максимальную стоимость покупки и минимальную стоимость продажи.

На сайте есть несколько баз данных, и номер интересующей нас базы данных мы передаем скрипту. Получается так:

```
loadSystemPrices(B3:B21,3012)
```

где `3012` — номер интересующей нас базы данных.

Как в «гуглотаблице» поставить быстрое переключение между номерами баз данных? Чтобы не было необходимости менять формулу или делать по таблице для каждой базы данных.

[Ссылка на «гугл докс»](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPAGr9dWrNwTvUwNFrEC2WNI6f0Tf5PKeHFRevdyGGI/edit#gid=1699203965) (сама формула находится в ячейке *С3* листа *Trash*).

[Ссылка на скрипт](https://github.com/fuzzysteve/eve-googledocs-script/blob/master/EveCentralPrices.gs).